# After extracting image from the word file create copy on the system

Tags: php, image, ms-word

> After successfully reading the msword file's image I displayed it.
>
> Now I want to copy that images. Image copy function working fine but image in crrupted format
>
> Code is

```
$document = 'wordfile.docx';
readZippedImages($document);
function readZippedImages($filename) {
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if (true === $zip->open($filename)) {
for ($i=0; $i<$zip->numFiles;$i++) {
$zip_element = $zip->statIndex($i);
if(preg_match("([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp))$)",$zip_element['name'])) {
saveImage('http://localhost/readfileimage/display.php?filename=".$filename."&index=".$i."');
echo "<image src='display.php?filename=".$filename."&index=".$i."' /><hr />";
}
}
}
}
function saveImage($path)
{
copy($path, rand().'-flower.jpg');
}
```

> Here is the code of display.php file

```
  /*Tell the browser that we want to display an image*/
      header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
  /*Create a new ZIP archive object*/
      $zip = new ZipArchive;

      /*Open the received archive file*/
      if (true === $zip->open($_GET['filename'])) {

  //$zip->open($path, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
  /*Get the content of the specified index of ZIP archive*/
          echo $zip->getFromIndex($_GET['index']);
      }

      $zip->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
function saveImage($path) {
  $imageUrl = $path;
  $contents = file_get_contents(trim($imageUrl));
  if ($contents) {
    file_put_contents('/path/to/save/flower.jpg', $contents);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue using this?

Comment: Have you face same issue?

Comment: Please try to fetch another image. may be image issue

Comment: I tried on many word file with lots of images. Now I updated the full code you can try it yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62312/discussion-between-roshan-dandgavhal-and-vinod).